# SQL script to update column values based on other column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, scripting

I am new to writing SQL scripts and I am using SQL Server.

I have a table of data:

[image]

As you can see some of the `race_title_short` values are NULL. I want to update the values in this column based on the `race_identifier_code`.

For example one of the `race_identifier` codes is CORL which has a `race_title_short` of Coral Cup.

One of the records has the race identified as CORL but has no `race_title_short`.

How do I update the NULL `race_title_short` based on the `race_identifier_code` which have race title shorts in?

Comment: Use an `UPDATE` statement: `UPDATE yourtable SET race_title_short = 'Coral Cup' WHERE race_identifier_code = 'CORL';` (syntax may vary depending on your RDBMS) Update the tags with that info and we can guide a bit better.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set race_title_short = (select max(t2.race_title_short)
                            from t t2
                            where t2.race_identifier_code = t.race_identifier_code
                           )
    where race_title_short is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

With a self join:

```
update t
set t.race_title_short = tt.race_title_short
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on tt.race_identifier_code = t.race_identifier_code
where t.race_title_short is null and tt.race_title_short is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

update t1 set t1.race_title_short = (select distinct race_title_short from test t2 where 
                             t2.race_identifier_code = t1.race_identifier_code
                            and t2.race_title_short is not null) from test t1